# define array name within a loop

Tags: variables, loops, idl-programming-language

I may be going about this the wrong way, but I'm trying define and fill arrays within a loop.

```
for i = 0,39 do begin

xx = long(findgen(n+1l)*sx + line1x[i]) 
sz = size(xx)
arrayname = 'line' + strtrim(i,2)
arrayname = findgen(3,sz[1])
arrayname[0,*] = xx
arrayname[1,*] = yy
arrayname[2,*] = vertline

endfor
```

This obviously won't work, but is there a way to use the string defined by 'line' + strtrim(i,2) to create and fill a new array upon each iteration? In this case I'd have 40 arrays with names line0...39. The difficult part here is that sz[1] varies, so I can't simply define one large array to hold everything.

Answer (score 3):

In idl 8.0 or later you could use the `HASH` datatype for this.

Your code would looks like this:

```
array_dict = hash()
for ii = 0,39 do begin
  xx = long(findgen(n+1l)*sx + line1x[ii]) 
  sz = size(xx)
  arrayname = 'line' + string(1, FORMAT='(i02)')
  array = findgen(3,sz[1])
  array[0,*] = xx
  array[1,*] = yy
  array[2,*] = vertline

  array_dict[arrayname] = array
endfor
```

You can now access your arrays by name:

```
line = array_dict['line01']
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's always the `execute` function, if you're in the mood for a filthy hack (and don't need it to run on an unlicensed virtual machine installation).

But have you considered declaring a 1-D array of pointers, where each element points to one of your 3 by sz subarrays?  That gives you some of the benefit of one big array,
without the constraint of all the subarrays having to have the same shape.
It might look something like this...

```
ptrs=ptrarray(40) ; Allocate an array of 40 pointers, initialized to null

for i = 0,39 do begin
  ; calculate sz, xx, yy, vertline
  dummy=findgen(3,sz[1])
  dummy[0,*] = xx
  dummy[1,*] = yy
  dummy[2,*] = vertline
  ptrs[i]=ptr_new(dummy) ; create copy of dummy on the heap, storing pointer in ptrs[i]

endfor

; To access the i-th subarray...

(*ptrs[i])[0,*] = new_xx
(*ptrs[i])[1,*] = new_yy
(*ptrs[i])[2,*] = new_vertline
```